# JPA: is possible to get the offset of a item in a query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm using a `PageRequest(offset, limit, sort)` and I know that one item is in some page of the query.

A priory, I would like to know the page where is the item in the paginated query to pass the right offset. Is that possible?

Comment: You should create a query with the same sorting to count the item position. Then calculate the item page number.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it's a hassle to get there as you need a special query to determine the position first. I would suggest you try a solution like [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence) which works on top of JPA/Hibernate and supports this exact use case: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#anchor-navigate-entity-page